# Remove nested tags insisde <a> tag using javascript regexp?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

This function removes any `<a>` tag in javascript

```
replace(/<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/i,"")
```

But It doesn't remove nested tags like It doesn't work on this tag

```
<a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/ardroid?a=AqChTdtuXxo:V799F6z5h7k:qj6IDK7rITs">
   <img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/ardroid?d=qj6IDK7rITs" border="0">
</a>
```

I want another regular expression that would eliminate any `<a>` tag with all its content

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1317805

Comment: processing HTML with regex is imposible to get correct in general http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags .

Comment: Use the DOM for this. Query the element then remove all its child nodes.

Comment: As far as I can tell the only reason it doesn't work for your example is because you need to use the single-line (dot all) modifier. [(?s)](http://regexr.com?37f2u) not because of the nested tag, just because it is over multiple lines.

Comment: @OGHaza - JavaScript doesn't support the `s` modifier. One must use something like `[\S\s]` instead of the dot to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @ridgerunner, ah thanks for the info, my mistake, still OP's problem has nothing to do with nested tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's recommended to use a dom based approach to pocessing html

using jQuery:

```
$('a').remove();
```

Although:...

this will probably work 95% of the time

```
/<a[\s\S]*?<\/a>/
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accurately use regex to process HTML, so you should use the DOM for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/EMd2e/

```
$('a').contents().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

as others have pointed out, it's not a good idea to parse HTML using regexp but your regexp needs some minor modifications to be able to do what you need

```
var s = '<a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/ardroid?a=AqChTdtuXxo:V799F6z5h7k:qj6IDK7rITs">\n\
   <img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/ardroid?d=qj6IDK7rITs" border="0">\n\
</a><span></span>';
s.replace(/<a\b[^>]*>([^]*)<\/a>/im,"") // result will be <span></span>
```

simply, you need to make it match against multiline strings, more info could be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: @ridgerunner, it's legal in javascript, try: `'hi'.match(/[^]/g) //["h", "i"]`

Comment: of course I tried it, here's the result on FF 25.0.1:
http://imagebin.org/280177 /cc @OGHaza

Comment: and of course here's the exact text from MDN that I've included in answer: Note that the m multiline flag doesn't change the dot behavior. So to match a pattern accross multiple lines the character set [^] can be used, it will match any character including newlines.

Comment: also tried it on chrome 31.0, and works as expected. result is: `<span></span>`

Comment: @everplays fair play, works fine for me in FF 25.0.1, Chrome 31.0, Safari 7.0 all on mac. -whoops got mixed up there, thought that was a reply from ridgerunner.

Comment: @OGHaza, @everplays - You were right and I stand corrected. JavaScript treats the expression: `[^]` as a negated empty character class which matches any one character. Most other languages however, treat this quite differently. A closing bracket placed at the beginning of a char class is treated literally and is the same as if it were escaped. i.e. `[]]` is equivalent to `[\]]` and `[^]]` is equivalent to `[^\]]`